# Heat transfer from stovetop through heated water to air

Tags: radiation, thermal-conductivity

This is a question about efficiency.

My understanding is that resistive heating is very efficient. So if I turn on an electric burner on the stove, once the stove+stovetop equalizes, radiation into the room is (ignoring electricity pricing) essentially just as efficient, given that the stove+stovetop are also re-radiating and being maintained by the burner's heat.

First, is that assumption anywhere near correct?

If it is, then this: If I put a large pot of water, lidded so as to minimize evaporation, and heat it below a boil on the same electric element given the above, then once the pot+water equalize, is the re-radiation from the pot, combined with the stove, stovetop, and burner as a system, basically equivalent to that of the bare burner?

Or are there energy losses of significance going on?

Comment: Please clarify as precisely as you can what you mean by "efficiency"; otherwise, the question is probably to vague to be answerable. For example, do you mean "(minimal) cost to keep a human comfortable 5 m away"? Details are important because an electric heater can get hot enough that radiation is important as well as conduction and convection. Right now, I don't see what "just as efficient" means or what the basis of comparison is.

Comment: I'm not asking about comfort. I'm asking if putting a pot of water on a stove, once thermally equalized, changes the amount of heat transferred to the surrounds as compared to no pot. I don't see how it could, but I'm no physicist.

Comment: It doesn't change the total rate of heat dissipation to the rest of the universe—that's just equal to the burner power, which I'm assuming remains constant—but it could change the nature of the heat transfer; for example, a red-hot burner radiates heat by line of sight over large distances, which isn't the case if you cover it with a pot (which acts as a [heat sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_sink)). Does this get at what you're asking about?

Comment: Yes, thank you. So the pot blocks and sinks the direct stovetop element heat radiation, and radiates in new directions once equalized, e.g. radially. Plus some hot vapor, because H2O. But the sum total is the same. Is that about it?

Comment: Yes. I ignored the phase change because of your lid assumption; a phase change further increases the complexity of the problem.

Comment: Write an answer and I'll upvote you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given power level, is the heat transfer from a stovetop through heated water to air invariant?

Yes and no.

Yes, the total dissipated heat flux to the rest of the universe is the same.

But no, the nature of this heat transfer can vary greatly. For example, putting a covered container of water on the burner can block radiative heat transfer from a red-hot burner, which otherwise would be easily seen from a hundred meters away, and replace it in part with greater convective heat transfer to the surrounding air. Here, the container is acting as a heat sink with much greater area than the original burner. The problem changes again if we allow evaporation, which can transport large amounts of heat through the latent heat of a phase change in conjunction with steam convection.